# Animate top property on relative positioned div css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I tried to animate the `top` property on a relative positioned div inside another div. When I hover over the footer the `top` property is triggered but not animated. I can't figure out why the animation doesn't play.

I made a pen of the issue, view it here [here](http://codepen.io/Jochim/pen/BjoNZz?editors=110).

CSS

```
footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
footer:hover .f-first {
  top: 5vh;
}
footer div {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.25, 1) 0.1s;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your non hovered element a starting `top` position to be transitioned:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWbPpa?editors=110)

```
.f-first {
  top: 0vh;
}
```

Full SCSS:

```
footer {
  background-color: darken(white, 5%);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  .f-first {
     top: 0vh;
  }
  &:hover {
    .f-first {
      top: 5vh;
    }
    .f-second {
    }
    .f-third {
    }
  }
  div {
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.25, 1) 0.1s;
  }
}
```